How to access properties in Collection laravel?
I can't access properties of my entity, I always get a response saying that the property in question does not exist in my Collection.
With this:
`$teste =  $this->user->with('sala')
        ->where('id', $idUserLogado)
            ->first();

  dd($teste->sala);`

get return normally collection:
`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1405 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\DashboardController.php:34
 #items: array:1 [▼
0 => 
App\Models
\
  Sala {#1412 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "salas"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:4 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "numero_sala" => "10A"
    "bloco_sala" => "A"
    "user_id" => 2
  ]
  #original: array:4 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: false
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
 ]
 #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}`

but when I try to access a property...
dd($teste->sala->numero_sala);
BOOM:
Property [numero_sala] does not exist on this collection instance.
WHAT?
please.
My methods are right, I don't think I know how to deal with the Collection, I'm reading the documentation but I can't find it.

dd($teste->sala->first()->numero_sala); - Collections are a wrapper for an Array, and trying to do ->sala->numeroa_sala fails, since the program doesn't know which Sala instance you're trying to access.

Read the documentation for how Arrays work in PHP before you try to understand how a Collection works, since again, a Collection is simply a wrapper for an Array. You could also iterate this, like foreach($teste->sala as $sala), then you can access $sala->numero_sala inside of that loop.

Your answer was amazing and it worked. THANKS

No problem  Sidenotes, you've got a Collection of 1 Sala instance, can there be more? If so, then you might want to consider renaming the method to salas (unless sala is already plural). Relationship names should match how many instances they return, and a hasMany() returns 0 or more, so the method name should be plural. If you only ever expect one, then change the method to a hasOne(), and $teste->sala->numero_sala would work as written. Just some Laravel conventions to consider. Cheers
